# download and then install the ubuntu programs

Tags: ubuntu

For Windows we can go to desired websites and then download programs and then install them. I have an Ubuntu machine that want like for windows download the programs and then install them rather than directly download and install into machine. In this case I can install those programs whenever I want. Is there a simple way to do such, for Ubuntu or other Linux-related OSs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. No problem in doing that. You can download the source code and compile yourself, or convert it to debian package.

use command `apt-get source <program name>` to get source code.

Details and more steps involved in installation in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get).

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to use for example aptitude instead of downloading the source code and compiling.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.
You can as with Windows search the net and find providers that have made .deb packages for their software, download it and install it at your leisure using dpkg or what ever GUI you have chosen to use.

You can also use `aptitude` with the `download` parameter instead of `install` to just download the software you want and then take a backup of the packages you wish to use.

```
aptitude download terminator
```

The above command would download the terminator package so that you can install it at your own chosen time and place.

You can of course also download the source code, compile it and install it at your leisure. But the advantages of aptitude, apt-get, dpkg and other software that follows the Ubuntu distribution are many and makes compiling your own software for special circumstances mostly.

My suggestions all require you to use the terminal for downloading. When installing you can use any GUI that you have available for this purpose.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you very much. But please remember I'm novice in that issue. I don't know how to use the "aptitude download terminator" command. And where to type it (in Windows machine? if so in run window? or...) or in Ubuntu machine. Please consider this scenario: I'm on my Windows machine and want to download a good video player for my Ubuntu machine and then after downloading that program copy it to my USB flash and then simply connect that USB to the Ubuntu machine and install that player. Now if possible, please guide me step by step to do that. Thank you again.